# SQL - Multiple PIVOT operator doesn't work with alias

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Test data:

```
CREATE table #user (ID INT)
insert into #user values (1)

CREATE table #type 
(
 subscriberId INT,
 typeId INT,
 typeValue NVARCHAR(256)
)
insert into #type values (1,1,'Type1')
insert into #type values (1,2,'Type2')
insert into #type values (1,3,'Type3')

CREATE table #category
(
 subscriberId INT,
 categoryId INT,
 categoryValue NVARCHAR(256)
)
insert into #category values (1,1,'Category1')
insert into #category values (1,4,'Category4')
insert into #category values (1,5,'Category5')
insert into #category values (1,6,'Category6')
```

I have a query, which works fine

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT t.subscriberId,
    t.typeId, t.typeValue,
    c.categoryId, c.categoryValue
    FROM #user u
    INNER JOIN #type t on t.subscriberId = u.id
    INNER JOIN #category c on c.subscriberId = u.id) target
PIVOT(
    max(typeValue)
    for typeId in ([1],[2],[3])
) as [pivot_table1]
PIVOT (
    max(categoryValue)
    for categoryId in ([4],[5],[6])
) as [pivot_table2]
```

But when I try to use the same Ids for categoryId and typeId:

```
for categoryId in ([1],[4],[5],[6])
```

I see an error:

> Msg 265, Level 16, State 1, Line 38 The column name "1" specified in
>   the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the
>   PIVOT argument. Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 39 The column '1'
>   was specified multiple times for 'pivot_table2'.

Also, I can't use `[pivot_table1].[1]]` instead of * , but it's possible when I use only one PIVOT operator.
Does someone have an idea of how can I fix it?
Expected result:
How can I use the same id(column's name) in both PIVOT?

Comment: This looks like you'd be better off with a Cross Tab; sample data and expected results will really help here.

Comment: @Larnu Done. Ready for review again

Comment: Can you include expected results?

Comment: Thanks for the DDL and DML, @BasilKosovan , that's the best way to supply sample data so well done, but we do need to know what you're end result should be.

Comment: @Larnu  Expected result is using the same column's name in both PIVOT. PeterHe already has provided a  solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the column being pivoted will be the columns of the results, so they can not have the same value to prevent duplicated column names. You can prefix the value for category to distinguish them:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT t.subscriberId,
    t.typeId, t.typeValue,
    N'c_'+CAST(c.categoryId as nvarchar(22)) AS categoryId, c.categoryValue
    FROM #user u
    INNER JOIN #type t on t.subscriberId = u.id
    INNER JOIN #category c on c.subscriberId = u.id) target
PIVOT(
    max(typeValue)
    for typeId in ([1],[2],[3])
) as [pivot_table1]
PIVOT (
    max(categoryValue)
    for categoryId in (c_1, c_4, c_5, c_6)
) as [pivot_table2]
```

Comment: Why it's not possible to use [pivot_table1].[1] when there are no column's name conflicts?

Comment: SQL Server only sees the last alias of the PIVOT. It represents all the columns of the final pivot results, e.g. you can specify SELECT [pivot_table2].[2]  FROM...

Answer (score 2):

*If* the answer from PeterHe provides the correct return dataset, then (as mentioned) a Cross tab would seem the better idea:

```
SELECT U.ID,
       MAX(CASE t.typeId WHEN 1 THEN t.typeValue END) AS [1],
       MAX(CASE t.typeId WHEN 2 THEN t.typeValue END) AS [2],
       MAX(CASE t.typeId WHEN 3 THEN t.typeValue END) AS [3],
       MAX(CASE c.categoryId WHEN 1 THEN c.categoryValue END) AS c_1,
       MAX(CASE c.categoryId WHEN 2 THEN c.categoryValue END) AS c_2, --Assumed wanted
       MAX(CASE c.categoryId WHEN 3 THEN c.categoryValue END) AS c_3, --Assumed wanted
       MAX(CASE c.categoryId WHEN 4 THEN c.categoryValue END) AS c_4,
       MAX(CASE c.categoryId WHEN 5 THEN c.categoryValue END) AS c_5,
       MAX(CASE c.categoryId WHEN 6 THEN c.categoryValue END) AS c_6
FROM #user u
     JOIN #type t ON u.ID = t.subscriberId
     JOIN #category c ON t.subscriberId = c.subscriberId
GROUP BY u.ID;
```

Comment: You'll have to test performance wise, but I've never had a Cross Tab perform worse than a `PIVOT`, @BasilKosovan. And a Cross tab is far easier to understand than a `PIVOT` in my view; plus it's far more flexible (as you can see here, where you can pivot on two tables in the same "breath").

Comment: But if I need to use these columns in order by and where clause it could be complicated

Comment: It's really not, @BasilKosovan . use a CTE if you need it in the `WHERE`, or use a [`HAVING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause (I.e. `HAVING MAX(CASE t.typeId WHEN 3 THEN t.typeValue END) = 3`). Columns can be referenced by their Alias in the `ORDER BY`; so that's a non-issue.